# How can I make a string of objects names in java

Tags: java, string, parsing

I would like to write a function that would enable me to do the following

1. inputs: variable number of objects of any type
2. output: a string that would be `NameObj1=ValueObj1, ..., NameObjN=ValueObjN`

All objects I would pass to the function would have a `toString()` method.

Example:

```
double x=1.1; int y=2; ClassA a 
theFunction(x,y,a)
=> this would output "x=1.1, y=1, a=[whatever a.toString() output]"
```

Is that possible ?

Comment: Objects do not have names. *Variables* have names. A variable refers to an object; you can have multiple variables referring to the same object. Also, arguments are passed by value, so `theFunction` does not know the variables that you passed into it. So what you want, is not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's something close:

you can write a var-arg function like so:

```
public static String describeArguments (Object... arguments) {
   StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
   int counter = 1;
   for (Object argument : arguments) {
      output.append("object #").append(counter++).append(": ").append(argument.toString());
   }
   return output.toString();
}
```

strictly speaking method arguments dont have names. you could retrieve the argument parameter name using reflection if the symbol tables werent stripped out @compile time, but its brutish and ugly.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of getting what you wrote to be the "name" of a variable, because the only way of referencing it, is by itself, and by value is not possible as well.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers and comments there is no "name of an object". But if the objects you are interested in are all fields of one class, you could write a function that uses reflection to access that objects fields and prints their names.

Take a look at the [reflection tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html). There is also an example that is very close to what you might have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map like

```
 Map<String,Object> map= new HashMap<String,Object>();
 map.put("x", 1.1);
 map.put("y",2);
 map.put("a", MyClass.class);
```

And call `theFunction(map)`, where theFunction is:

```
 public void theFunction(HashMap<String,Object> list) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String key:list.keySet()) {
    try {           
       Object currentObject = list.get(key);
       sb.append(key+"="+currentObject.getClass().getMethod("toString").invoke(currentObject)+" ");
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    }
   System.out.println(sb.toString());
   }
```